# Using IronPython in C#

Tags: c#, ironpython

I've recently discovered IronPython in C# and only tutorials I found were how to use python script in C#, but I've noticed, that IronPython has classes and methods you can use directly in C# like :  `PythonIterTools.product some_pr = new PythonIterTools.product();` and others, can anyone explain how does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parts of IronPython's standard library are implemented in C#, mainly because the equivalents in CPython are written in C. You can access those parts directly from a C# (or any other static .NET  language) directly, but they're not intended to be used that way and may not be easy to use.